# Passing json data from Javascript to PHP using JQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I want to pass json data from my Javascript script to the PHP one and I am kinda struggling with it.

First here is the code:

```
var d = new Date(),
    DayOfWeek = d.getDay(),
    Actual_Day = d.getDate(),
    Month = d.getMonth() + 1;
if (Month < 10) {
    Month = '0' + Month;
}
var Year = d.getFullYear();
var Date = Year.toString() + Month.toString() + Day.toString();
var Hour = d.getHours(),
    Minutes = d.getMinutes();

var data = {
    "YearKey": Year,
    "MonthKey": Month,
    "Actual_DayKey": Actual_Day,
    "DayOfWeekKey": DayOfWeek,
    "DateKey": Date,
    "HourKey": Hour,
    "MinutesKey": Minutes

};

jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'index.php',
    type: 'json',
    data: data,
    success: function(data) {
        console.log('success!');

    }
});
```

In my PHP script, I've tried to be sure that I have a value but it seems to not be the case:

```
if (isset($_POST['YearKey'])) {echo $_POST['YearKey']; exit();}
```

Any solutions, advices would be appreciated!

Comment: What response do you get? Have you tried to do a var_dump or if and see what is actually being sent to your PHP script? Also, not sure if you set jQuery to be jQuery, but usually jQuery is called using the dollar sign:
`$.ajax({ ... });`

Comment: Do you have any js errors in your console?

Comment: Try to do `alert(data)` instead, as it's easier to check what your actual result is. Also your expecting a JSON response, so in your php you should do `echo json_encode($_POST['YearKey']);`

Answer (score 1):

In your jQuery , `type:ajax` means you prepare the function to an ajax **response**

in your case you need to send a JSON

put that line in your client code

```
data: {data:JSON.stringify(data)}
// will send the JSON string with the request in a parameter called data
```

on your server decode it

```
<?php
$data = json_decode($_POST['data']);
```

Comment: I've tried your solution, but when it still seems that $_POST['data'] is empty because it does not pass the isset test

Comment: @AbdoulGuisset did your browser log `"success"` or not ? if not then supply an error handler to the ajax object `error:function (j,t,e){console.log(t)}`

Comment: my browser logged "success" in your example and also mine. Is there anyway that I can track ajax response? Thanks

Comment: @AbdoulGuisset your browser network activity monitor must be your friend when you debug web applications, you will find it in the browser developer tools , along with the debugger and console

Comment: @AbdoulGuisset try to do  these 2 tests please, **1**: replace your data object at the java script with hard-coded values `var data = { "YearKey": 5, "MonthKey": 5,"Actual_DayKey": 5, "DayOfWeekKey": 5, "DateKey": 5, "HourKey": 5, "MinutesKey": 5 };` **2**- echo anything from the PHP code without depending on the testing if `YearKey` is set or not, and tell me what you get

Comment: I've tried to echo any data but to my surprise it does not show anything. I still have the success message though. Do you think the problem lies in the JS script?

Comment: replace your `console.log('success')` with `console.log(data)` and on the first line in your PHP script use `die('hello client');` and see if it's logged in the console or not, and tell the result. *(note: since you didn't present the actual code that can reproduce your problem,  debugging the code will be hard)*

Comment: If I use console.log(data) + die('hello client') it prints my entire HTML page with HTML page until it arrives at 'hello client'. 
The actual code is a single .php file with a `<script> ` tag that contains the JavaScript code shown in the question and `<?php` tag that contains the php part of it.

Thanks for your support!

Comment: Did you hard code the data object as I told you [in the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45246161/passing-json-data-from-javascript-to-php-using-jquery/45246238?noredirect=1#comment77460085_45246238) ? and then try your test on PHP `if (isset($_POST['YearKey'])) {echo $_POST['YearKey']; exit();}`

Answer (score 0):

It’s actually quite simple. In order to pass variables through to your PHP file from your AJAX request, you need to edit the URL portion of the request. For example, if your url looks like this:

```
url: "name_of_file.php/?value=VARIABLE-STUFF&more=VARIABLE-STUFF&etc=etc"
```

The variable values of value, more, and etc will be accessible in your PHP file. Then use:

```
$variable_name = $_GET['value'];
```

to store the variable ‘value’ into ‘variable_name’ for use in PHP file, and etc for any other variables you pass to the PHP file. For your case, I would suggest just passing the entire data object into the PHP file and working from there.

```
url: "index.php/?object=" + data
```

Then in PHP file do:

```
$object_name = $_GET['object'];
```

Now, your data object in your HTML file will be usable in your PHP file under the variable $object_name.

Answer (score 0):

```
file_get_contents(php://input)
```

gets the raw POST data like JSON object that cannot be decoded to $_POST.

```
<?php
$data = var_dump(file_get_content('php://input'));
```

Answer (score -1):

you need to check all posted data having values or not

so please check with `console.log(data);` .

i think it may help you .

Comment: Thanks for taking the time of helping me ! 

Do you mean in the success callback? Because the variable is correctly defined (I've tried to display it using console.log(data))

Comment: @AbdoulGuisset If you are getting the correct result, what is the issue?

Comment: @Abdoul Guisset  No , i am talking before the passed the data in ajax.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, provide answers that [don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). Also, the [StackOverflow Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) is a very helpful resource!